# QAtomic long long

Tags: c++, qt

Есть ли в `Qt` аналог `std::atomic` с типом `long long`?

```
atomic<long long> result = 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть. [`QAtomicInteger<long long>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qatomicinteger.html)